# How to DRY up controller code which involves views code as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

In my Rails 3 app, I have a number of models with a boolean field `disabled`. In controllers for these models, I use a custom action `disable` to toggle the `disabled` field using Ajax.

Example (For client),

```
# routes.rb
resources :clients do
  member do
    get :toggle_disable, to: 'clients#disable', as: :disable
  end
end

# clients_controller.rb
def disable
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  @client.update_attribute :disabled, !@client.disabled
  render 'clients/update_client', format: :js
end

# update_client.js.erb
$('#client-<%= @client.id %>-details').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'clients/client', client: @client) %>");
```

I have this code for at least ten resources in my application.

**QUESTION**

How do I go about DRYing up this code and add actions for these boolean fields dynamically? I could have gone with creating a parent controller or module but I am not sure how will I take care of the views code.

I should be able to do something like this

```
#clients_controller.rb
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  add_toggle_action :disable
end
```

Comment: the difference is only the field name in update_attribute?

Comment: @apneadiving I want to put the `disable` action from all the controllers at a single place. And willing to achieve the same for `expire` actions. I am not trying to merge `disable` and `expire` actions in a single function.

Comment: understood but how the `expire` actions should look like?

Comment: If I get the code going for `disable` action, I can extend that code myself for `expire` and `trial` actions. I just need pointers to get started. Whether a module is sufficient here or I should be thinking about creating a gem.

Comment: I don't understand what you need nor what `add_toggle_action :expire`is supposed to do

Comment: `add_toggle_action :disable` must define `disable` action for current controller as shown in the example. Also, it should be able to render the `js.erb` template placed somewhere in `views/shared/update_examplemodelname.js.erb`. So, in my controller, I'll just add one line `add_toggle_action :disable` and will automagically get the action definition as well as views template.

Comment: it's clear for `disable`since you gave the example but what code should be in the `expire`action?

Comment: Updated the question. Just forget about `expire` action. I have this `disable` action in 10 controllers and I want to refactor it to a module or gem. Can you help me now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main ways to share methods:

- inheritance: define your action in `ApplicationController`
- mixins: add your method in a module and include the module in the appropriate controllers

Since you want only some controllers to get the method, I'll head towards mixin.

Your controller action must use a view with a full path, not relative, something like:

```
render '/shared/clien/update', format: :js
```

Lastly, you'll have to define all routes.

Comment: I went with packing the code in a module and including that module in desired controllers.